# Exporting Table to Excel using xml template

Tags: javascript, excel

I can download and export my html table to excel correctly but is there a way that I can change the xlsx file name instead of using the default 'download.xlsx', just want to make the download file as 'myTemplate'.xlsx.

Here my function that I am currently using:

```
 var tableToExcel = (function () {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
        return function (table, name) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
            window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
        }
    })()
```

Any suggestions/comments TIA

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind just got new solution and used this as referece:

https://www.codexworld.com/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Tag from and then add link to it

```
   const tableExelExport =  ( function () {
  let uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
       template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
       base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) },
       format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p] }) }
  return async function (table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    let ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
    let downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    let rp_name = await localStorage.getItem("@report_name")
    downloadLink.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    downloadLink.download = rp_name;
    downloadLink.click();
    // window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
```